# Android - user-defined delay is used in registerListener(). Not working, why?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am trying to read the values from the android phone sensors.
I initialize the sensors as follows:

```
private void sensorInit() {
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
}
```

Then I can get ~350 samples/second.

But then to save power, I hope to slow it down.
So I modify SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST to 1000.
I wish the sensor delay to be 1000ms.
But obviously it is not working, because I still get a rate of ~350 samples/second.

From Android page:

> public boolean registerListener (SensorListener listener, int sensors,
>   int rate, Handler handler)
>
> Parameters
>
> listener: sensor listener object
>
> sensors: a bit masks of the sensors to register to
>
> rate: rate of events. This is only a hint to the system. events may be
>   received faster or slower than the specified rate. Usually events are
>   received faster. The value must be one of SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL,
>   SENSOR_DELAY_UI, SENSOR_DELAY_GAME, or SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST. ***or,
>   the desired delay between events in microseconds.*** Specifying the
>   delay in microseconds only works from Android 2.3 (API level 9)
>   onwards. For earlier releases, you must use one of the SENSOR_DELAY_*
>   constants.
>
> handler: The Handler the sensor events will be delivered to.

Anybody can help me?

How can I really slow the sensor sampling down to save power?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmmmm you say you set it to 1000 to get samples at 1 second, but the documentation states that the delay is in *microseconds*. 1 sec in microsecs = 1000000 . Have you tried with that number?

Comment: @dmon  OMG, I am so silly. I just tried. It works but nor as expected. I set the delay to be 10,000,000 microsec = 10 s. Then I make my phone sample for 180s. As expected, I should end up with 18 samples. Whereas I end up with 18345 samples. It is indeed smaller compared with the previous 63773 using SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST. But not small enough...

Comment: Oh well, I guess it was worth a shot :)

Comment: Maybe a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873545/custom-sensor-event-rates-dont-seem-to-work-with-sensormanager-registerlisten .  And, 7 years later, it's still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL` or `SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI`

Comment: I know this. But I want to SELF-DEFINE my sensor delay. These 2 are fixed delays. What if I want a 1800ms delay?

Comment: I do not think you can set your own the delay rate.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener(android.hardware.SensorListener, int, int)            here it says that we can do it.

Comment: I has been a while since I work with sensor but the document also state that the rate is "This is only a hint to the system".

Comment: ok thanks. May I ask what is the 4th argument, Handler handler? It seems that once I have the 4th parameter, I can set the desired rate.

Comment: I have no idea, I never use it before. I think if you define your listener inside a handler (thread), then you have to specify this handler.

Comment: what about  sensorManager.registerListener(this,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);?                               I mean I dunno whether I should do this during my sensor initialization. I only see this method is called in onResume from teh Google sample code. I don't understand why. So I do it twice, both in initialization and onResume. Is that ok?

Comment: What is your question? I do not understand what do you want to ask? If your question concerning handler than "this" has to be in the same thread that registers the listener.

Comment: I am asking where I should use the statement: sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST); should I use it in onCreate() or onResume(). I think it is like an initialization and thus should be used in onCreate(). But the sample code given uses this in onResume.

Comment: Depend on your use. If you do not need sensor values when the activity is onPause, then you should register in onResume and unregister in onPause. Otherwise, onCreate and onDestroy or onStart and onStop

Answer (score 1):

To contribute a bit:

If you use any of the recommended values eg `SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL` or `SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI` than these will be used. If you take a look on the implementation:

```
private static int getDelay(int rate) {
        int delay = -1;
        switch (rate) {
            case SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST:
                delay = 0;
                break;
            case SENSOR_DELAY_GAME:
                delay = 20000;
                break;
            case SENSOR_DELAY_UI:
                delay = 66667;
                break;
            case SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL:
                delay = 200000;
                break;
            default:
                delay = rate;
                break;
        }
        return delay;
    }
```

You can see that the `delay` will default to any other value except the below :

```
/** get sensor data as fast as possible */
    public static final int SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST = 0;
    /** rate suitable for games */
    public static final int SENSOR_DELAY_GAME = 1;
    /** rate suitable for the user interface  */
    public static final int SENSOR_DELAY_UI = 2;
    /** rate (default) suitable for screen orientation changes */
    public static final int SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL = 3;
```

So as long as your value is not 0,1,3 then you will be ok and yours should be used.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative I have used in my projects. It goes like this:

1. Set an Alarm (`android.app.AlarmManager`) that would be `setRepeating` every `x` seconds.
2. In the `onReceive` of the alarm `registerListener` with the sensor setting of your convenience.
3. In the `SensorEventListener`'s `onSensorChanged` use the `event`'s values as you need. Then `unregisterListener`.

Steps 2 and 3 will repeat every `x` seconds.

I wish I would paste in all the code but it's quite long and intertwined with other functionality and I am sure you can find all the details online.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention, that param *samplingPeriodUs* takes microseconds. 
So if you want your updates with 1s period. You should pass 1_000_000 to function