# Sensors sampling rate is always too high

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

I'm writing an Android logging application that runs as a background service and logs sensor data.
Here's an example of my code to start logging the Gravity Sensor:

```
public void StartLogging(int intervalInMilliseconds) {
    mySensorManager.registerListener(this, myGravitySensor, intervalInMilliseconds * 1000); //millisec * 1000 = microsec
}
```

However, I have a problem: the sample rate I set is completely ignored and the actual one is much, MUCH faster.
For example: even if I set a very slow sample rate of 10000000 microseconds (aka: 10000 milliseconds, or 10 seconds) I actually receive updates about a dozen times every second, which is more than a hundred times faster than I requested!

I read in the documentation that the interval is not meant to be strictly precise, but here we're talking about a difference of at least two orders of magnitude, which is absurd!

I know that I can just compare timestamps and only log, say, one event every 100, but the problem is that I'm trying to minimize power consumption, and I imagine that waking the CPU once every 10 seconds would have quite a different impact on the battery than waking it ten times every second.

I'm also aware that I can pass a fourth parameter that  sets how much time the sensor events can stay in the queue before being delivered, however this doesn't seem to have any noticeable effect either.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It might just be that the sensor in the phone you're using doesn't have an interval parameter and just has on and off modes.

Comment: "the interval is not meant to be strictly precise". That's not what it says, it says "This is only a hint to the system. Events may be received faster or slower than the specified rate. Usually events are received faster." This is not about "precision", you simply cannot control it, you can only "hint".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to other answers it's simply not possible:
[Android - user-defined delay is used in registerListener(). Not working, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783325/android-user-defined-delay-is-used-in-registerlistener-not-working-why)

If you can't make it work with the samplerate parameter, try using the predefined samplerate parameters and see if they make a difference.

If the samplerate is still too high you could use a counter value and only call the event every X samples.

Comment: Seems quite inefficient that the framework can't limit the rate, especially in a mobile environment. Even if the sensor itself is always on invoking my listener 100 times faster than required sounds like it would incur quite a significant overhead. I was thinking, as a workaround, to just register the listener, do one single poll and then unregister it. This, too, sounds wasteful, but not as much as the constant calls. At any rate, marked as accepted, since it seems there's no other way around it. It still bothers me tho...

Comment: Yes indeed. My guess is that android is sampling with a (mostly) fixed samplerate and they thought about using a prescaler to provide custom samplerates but didn't include it? I would recommend doing some profiling between the counter and the register/unregister method, just to be sure which one is faster.

Answer (score 2):

It will work in some phones an might not work in others, actually it dependes about the sensor that the phone is using and other factors.

You should not rely on that value and should filter unwanted values depending about your desired rate.

Cheers !!!

Answer (score 0):

While "SensorManager is free to give you more samples than you asked for" is a good answer, it doesn't manage to explain why. I have inferred the following two explanations that may or may not be true across all devices:

If two components request sensor readings at different frequencies, they will both receive data at the highest rate requested, which makes sense from an efficiency point of view depending on the sensor type. Note that this is also true across processes, so a background service for detecting handset shake gestures can influence the shared rate.

Sensor rates can combine in unexpected ways. For instance, the camera reads the accelerometer at a modest 10Hz to determine orientation and the aforementioned shake-gesture-detector might run the gyro at 20Hz. Now a third component that uses TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR might want to run at SENSOR_DELAY_GAME, which is usually 50Hz. Because this last sensor is (usually) a soft fusion of the accelerometer and the gyro, it appears to demand they both run at the same frequency, but is unable to work out what that should be and gives up and runs at a jaunty 1KHz (on at least one of my devices).